# How to delete data in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to delete a key, but I have not been capable of achieve it. I'm trying with:

```
      ref.child("notifications").once("value", function(usersSnap) {
         var i = 0
         usersSnap.forEach(function(reciptsSnap) { //for every user
            reciptsSnap.forEach(function(reciptSnap) {

                  reciptSnap.forEach(function(c) {

if (reciptSnap.key=="jkk....."){
console.log("removed date nad its parent"+reciptSnap.key+" "+c.val())
reciptSnap.key.remove()  //did not work brings remove is not a function
}
```

[image]

Comment: That sounds *horribly* expensive: downloading all data to delete one item. You should ensure that you have the data in a format that allows efficient querying to get the record to delete. If you need to delete based on timestamp, store a list of items with their timestamp (so single level deep) or even put the IDs/paths in date-range buckets.

Comment: In fact i want to delete all the expired ids but I dont know how to use remove()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reciptSnap` is a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), which contains data from a Database location.
It cannot be removed directly.

You can use:

```
reciptSnap.ref.remove()
```