# Deleting a node from firebase database using firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to make a firebase cloud function to delete a node from Firebase Database. The log messages show that the function executed "ok" but it doesn't seem to remove any element from the database. I wrote the function taking help from the accepted answer in [How to delete data in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986989/how-to-delete-data-in-firebase)
Here is the snippet of the code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//path is defined as the value to be deleted,
console.log("Deleting element " + path);
var ref = admin.database().ref("/")
ref.orderByValue().equalTo(path).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log("Snapshot.ref = " + snapshot.ref);
    snapshot.ref.remove();
    return;
});
```

Also, in the above code, "Deleting element path_value" does show up in the log but Snapshot.ref = ... doesn't show up.

I don't have enough credits to embed images yet so here is a link to my database
[Structure of Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsY7m.jpg)

Comment: I think the selection is wrong.

Comment: How are you triggering the function? Cloud Functions for Firebase run once they are triggered by an event. What is the event you're using to trigger this? An HTTP trigger? A Database write event?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the selection is wrong. Double check that ref.orderByValue().equalTo(path) is actually equal to something.

```
ref.once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
    // handle read data.
  });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference

```
var adaRef = admin.database().ref('users/ada');
adaRef.remove()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Remove succeeded.")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
  });
```

Comment: This works, although not quite as expected; it deleted all the contents of my database. The log shows "Snapshot.ref = https://application.firebaseio.com/". Could you help me navigate to the correct reference location?

Comment: In Firebase, you can navigate to a node, then copy the URL. This should help you find the exact location you want. In your example, var ref = admin.database().ref("/"), "/" should be a path to the nodes you want to delete.

Comment: Thanks. That should help me find my way through. I have accepted your answer