# Firebase cloud functions: Delete specific node/data

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database of chatrooms & I would like to delete chatrooms when they get to a certain age(say 12 hours) via HTTPS trigger, or any trigger really.
All my chatrooms have a timeCreated attribute, & I found some samples for deleting data but ALL my data gets deleted.

My guess is I'm not navigating to the right path or something. The whole "chat_rooms" node gets deleted, not just the singular old chatroom I want gone.

My nodeJS/Firebase CF code

[image: screenshot]

My database structure

[image: database structure]

JSON FILE

```
{
  "chat_rooms" : {
    "room1" : {
      ".priority" : "9y1btvc14n",
      "g" : "9y1btvc14n",
      "l" : [ 33.8696853, -98.534908 ],
      "timeCreated" : 1508634704
    },
    "room A" : {
      ".priority" : "9y1btvc161",
      "chat_messages" : {
        "-Kx0d6aU0vfcH3OuOI9X" : {
          "Nicholas R Castro" : "haha OMG"
        }
      },
      "g" : "9y1btvc161",
      "l" : [ 33.8697009, -98.5349073 ],
      "timeCreated" : 1508634797
    }
  },
  "usernames" : {
    "Mick Mastro" : "Knx3DCMTTZhDfgU3uBFpRQIQoJr1",
    "Rick Dastro" : "Tv6PkDZ2NpX3TPgcqEPg9LNSilR2"
  }
}
```

CloudFunction NodeJs file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

//the seconds since Jan 1, 1970 midnight
var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
const chatRoomsRef = functions.database.ref('chat_rooms');
const chatRoomsRef2 = admin.database().ref('chat_rooms');

exports.deletePractice = functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
    var resultString = "Deleting these: ";
    chatRoomsRef2.once('value')
            .then(function(snapshot){
                        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapShot){
                            var roomName = snapshot.key;
                            var uniqueRoomName = childSnapShot.key;
                            console.log(roomName); // "chat_rooms"
                            console.log(childSnapShot.key); // the unique room name

                            console.log(childSnapShot.child('timeCreated').val());
                            console.log(seconds);

                            if( ( seconds - childSnapShot.child("timeCreated").val() )  > 5){
                                const now = Date.now();
                                const cutoff = now - 5;
                                console.log("If statement passed3!");
                                const oldItemsQuery = chatRoomsRef2.orderByChild('timeCreated').endAt(cutoff);
                                return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then( snapshot => {
                                    //create a map with all the children need to be removed
                                    const updates = {};
                                    snapshot.forEach(child => {
                                        updates[child.key] = null;
                                    });
                                    return chatRoomsRef2.update(updates);
                                });

                            }
                        });
            });
res.status(200).send(resultString);
});
```

Comment: I used this answer to guide me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224938/deleting-a-node-from-firebase-database-using-firebase-cloud-functions
but I'm encountering the same problem as him(everything gets deleted), and he never posted a resolution.

Comment: You've included links to pictures of the code and the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual code and the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use them to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Okay I will do that tonight. Thanks.